# Wordpress Resetting wp_options Rows

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm attempting to import a SQL dump into the wp_options table.  After the import, and before attempting to load the site, the values are appearing correctly in PhpMyAdmin.  However, certain option values are reset as soon as  the site is loaded by navigating to the domain in a browser. I'm wondering if there is some sort of fallback built into wordpress to reset corrupt values?  Does anybody know about anything along those lines in wordpress?

Comment: Yes, there's an elaborate little options dance that goes on at each request startup in WordPress. If you're migrating a site and you're new to all this, use one of the migration plugins.

Comment: You'll want to be a bit more specific so we can help. Which options are changing? What are their values like before & after?